# Asp.net application Running in IIS6 Server?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to Run Asp.Net Application in IIS6 server which is developed using asp.net framework 4.0?

Please provide the steps to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a separate application pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757073%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for your 4.0 applications and make that run 4.0 or even better have an application pool per application so you isolate them.

If you're upgrading you might want to have a look at this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2006/05/30/ASPNet_5F00_regiis.exe-tool_2C00_-setting-the-default-version-without-forcing-an-upgrade-on-all-sites.aspx) on how to set the framework version from command line.

Comment: @user3635084 always marks as answer if you need it helpful